# How to filter Many2one value depend another field?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

please I have a custom module here is a capture :

[image]

then I go to Sales order and modify the module sale.order.line i add some fields in relation with my custom module

[image]

Now my request is in ligne contrat i want only lignes in the contrat

for example if i choose **Contrat 01** only ligne in **Contrat 01**  like this

[image]

here is my code :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a domain in the field definition in your XML:

```
<field name="contrat_name_id"/>
<field name="contrat_lignes_id" domain="[('ligne_ids', '=', contrat_name_id)]"/>
```

This will filter contrat_lignes_id to only show records where ligne_ids matches what you entered for contrat_name_id on that line.

Answer (score 1):

What @djames did will work only in this form view if you want
to have this behavior in all your `sale.order.line` views use python 
to do this job for you.

```py
 class bons_lines(model.Model):
      _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

      # your new fields
      ....
      ....


      @api.onchange('contrat_name_id')
      def onchange_contrat_name(self):
          if self.contrat_name_id:
              # add the domain
              self.contrat_lignes_id = False # force the user to reselect the contrat_lignes_id if he changes the contrat name
              return {'domain': {'contrat_lignes_id': [('ligne_ids', '=', self.contrat_name_id.id)]}}
          else:
              # remove the domain 
              return {'domain': {'contrat_lignes_id': []}}
```

This way you will not have to add the domain in every XML view you declare.